# Integration by substitution vs. polynomial expansion first....different results??

Tags: integration, polynomials, definite-integrals, substitution

I came across a textbook problem that showed an integral solved with the substitution method:

$$\int_a^b(b-x)^2dx = \left(-\frac{(b-x)^3}{3}\right)\Biggl\vert_a^b$$

I then attempted to solve the same definite integral by expanding out the polynomial first and then integrating.  Step 1 I got this:

$$\int_a^b(b^2 - 2bx +x^2)dx$$

Next, I integrated each part of the polynomial and got this:

$$=(b^2x - bx^2 + \frac{x^3}{3})\Biggl\vert_a^b$$

I must have done something wrong here since these results are not equivalent.  Where am I missing something?  Thanks for your help!

Comment: maybe you could double check, I think that they are equivalent.

Comment: I believe they are equivalent if you substitute in the $a$ and $b$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you pretend that

$$\int_a^b(b^2 - 2bx +x^2)\ dx = \left(-\frac{b^3}3 +  b^2x - bx^2 + \frac{x^3}{3}\right)\Biggl\vert_a^b$$

by setting the integration constant to $-\frac{b^3}3$, you should see that the two approaches give the same result.

Comment: Thanks for this!  I had forgotten that even though it's a definite integral, an integration constant is still involved and gets cancelled out.  This makes sense now as to how the two approaches are still actually equivalent.  I appreciate it!

Answer (score 3):

Not sure why you think the results are not equivalent.

If you evaluate the first, you get
\begin{align*}
\left.\left(-\frac{(b-x)^3}{3}\right)\right|_a^b &= -\frac{(b-b)^3}{3} + \frac{(b-a)^3}{3}\\
&= \frac{1}{3}b^3 - b^2a + ba^2 - \frac{1}{3}a^3.
\end{align*}

On the other hand, if you evaluate your second expression, you get
\begin{align*}
 \left.\left(b^2x-bx^2 +\frac{x^3}{3}\right)\right|_a^b &= b^3 - b^3 + \frac{b^3}{3} - b^2a + ba^2 - \frac{a^3}{3}\\
&= \frac{1}{3}b^3 - b^2a + ba^2 -\frac{1}{3}a^3,
\end{align*}
Exactly the same answer. Just because they look different at first glance does not mean they are different.

Comment: Great explanation!  I was forgetting that the constant term differences don't really mean a different result when considering definite integrals since the terms cancel out anyway.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

$$I(x)=\int(b-x)^2dx$$
Let $u=b-x$. Therefore $dx=-du$
$$I(x)=-\int u^2du=\frac{-1}{3}u^3+C=\frac{-1}{3}(b-x)^3+C$$
Thus:
$$I(b)-I(a)=\frac{-1}{3}((b-b)^3-(b-a)^3)=\frac{(b-a)^3}{3}$$

Answer (score 0):

It's your first integral which is wrong, use a substitution $u=b-x$ to transform the integral:

$$\int_{a}^{b}(b-x)^{2}dx=\int_{0}^{b-a}u^{2}du$$

If you go through the algebra, this is the same as your second integral.

Comment: Why do you think the first integral is wrong? You get the same final answer...

Comment: Note that $(b-x)^{2}=(x-b)^{2}$, so your sign is wrong.

Comment: No, the sign is not wrong. And you can verify that by the easy task of differentiating $-\frac{(b-x)^3}{3}$ and verifying that you get $(b-x)^2$. Both answers yield $\frac{1}{3}(b-a)^3$. There is no error; you are mistaken in thinking that there is one.

Comment: If you set $u=b-x$, then $du=-dx$; the integral becomes $\int_a^b (b-x)^2\,dx = \int_{b-a}^0 -u^2\,du = -\frac{1}{3}u^3 |_{b-a}^0$. Then substituing back you get $-\frac{1}{3}(b-x)^3|_a^b$, which is what the OP has. There is no error.

Comment: See my answer down below for the work on the substitution

Comment: Downvoted until the incorrect assertion that the “first integral [...] is wrong” is edited; it is not wrong, it’s just different from what this poster would do.